# Is there really no supported Eclipse Plug-In for Mono?

Tags: c#, .net, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, mono

I am a happy user of the .Net Framework, but since one year I am also a happy OS X user. Mostly for development I reboot using Windows for developing .NET stuff. Just I tried the first time Mono Develop and find there are many cool things like MonoMac (I didn't try them already but it seems to be quite funny).

But trying MonoDevelop for one hour I had 2 crashes (while moving a file). Right now I am asking my self why did the Mono team creates a new IDE instead of creating a good Plug-In for such a cool IDE like Eclipse?

Searching on Google returns 3 or 4 projects but it doesn't seem they're really supported...

Right?

Comment: I spend 50% of my dev time in MonoDevelop and have not have it crash on me for a year or so - which version did you download and are you using Lion?

Comment: @john84: 2.4.2 is quite old, you should try more recent version. Eclipse won't be really more useful than any text editor without syntax analysis, code completion and refactoring. And you definitely won't have them better than in MonoDevelop (especially the newer one). If the newer version crashes as much, post the bug report ;)

Comment: MonoDevelop 2.8.6.3 is available on http://monodevelop.com/Download, with improved functionality and a new GTK# stack, that is stable under Lion.

Comment: Try it - I (and many other .Net devs) love it

Comment: Oh really, there is 2.8.x out :D...

Comment: Just out of interest, how would one find such an old version of MonoDevelop? Googling for "monodevelop" points to the current version.

Comment: No I did download a while ago, and today as I found the file in my Downloads Directory, I took a look on it ;-). But even the 2.8 did crash two times :-( ...

Comment: Well, if it is reproducible, then post the bug report.